# Ошибка типа данных Python

Tags: python, telegram, бот, telethon

```
from telethon import functions, types
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests




api_id = №№№№№
api_hash = №№№№№
client = TelegramClient("test", api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
print("STARTED")

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=["moscowach", "moscowtop", 
                            "moscowlenta", "DtRoad", "mosmap", "kim_online_rus"]))
def yandex(url):
    URL = 'https://newssearch.yandex.ru/news/' \
      'search?text=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0&sortby=date'
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    postes = soup.findAll("article", class_="news-search-story news-search__main-item mg-grid__item")

    for post in postes:
        title = post.a.text
        url = post.a['href']
@client.on(events.NewMessage(yandex = yandex))


async def normal_handler(event):
        if isinstance(event.chat, types.Channel):
            posting = url
            username = event.chat.username
            rdy = "@" + str(username)
            await client.send_message("https://t.me/kek3214", rdy)
            await client.send_message("https://t.me/kek3214", event.message)
            
        
        
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Система работает так, что с помощью Telethon я беру информацию с ТГ каналов и направляю ее в свой ТГ канал, но я еще захотел спарсить яндекс новости и всунул парсер сюда, при вызове выдает ошибку типа данных сижу ломаю голову :/

Вот сама ошибка

```
STARTED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/javadick/Загрузки/BotRiver1-main/mae123.py", line 28, in <module>
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(yandex = yandex))
TypeError: NewMessage.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'yandex'
```

Comment: Укажите полный текст ошибки со стекртейсом. А api токен лучше нигде не светить.

Comment: @insolor спасибо за замечание, исправил и добавил саму ошибку, забыл :/

Comment: Судя по документации, у NewMessage действительно нет параметра yandex: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/events.html#telethon.events.newmessage.NewMessage Скорее всего вам нужно было написать func=yandex

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, помогло исправить эту ошибку, но сам кусок кода так и не сработал :(, буду думать